# libgdx ram increase game freez maybe wrong in assets

Tags: android, libgdx

i have problem with Assets i think. I cant run the game at adroid device because of ram. i have 200mb free ram in my device but app cant run and close. when run it on pc many times run normal with 200-300mb ram and some times increase and increase 1.5gb -2gb... and the game not respond.

i ll put my code and ill show you what i have try to solve this. Im new and maybe i have few mistakes.

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

public MainMenuScreen menu_screen;
public GameScreen game_screen;
public HelpScreen help_screen;
public LevelScreen level_screen;
public LoadingScreen loading_screen;

int delay = 0;

@Override
public void create() {
    loading_screen = new LoadingScreen(this);
    setScreen(loading_screen);
    AssetsGame.load();
    AssetsLoad.load();
    AssetsMenu.load();
    Timer.schedule(new Task(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setScreen(setMainMenuScreen());
        }
    }, delay);
}

public Screen setGameScreen() {
    game_screen = new GameScreen(this);
    return game_screen;
}

public Screen setMainMenuScreen() {
    menu_screen = new MainMenuScreen(this);
    return menu_screen;
}

public Screen setMenuScreen() {
    menu_screen = new MainMenuScreen(this);
    return menu_screen;
}

public Screen setLevelScreen() {
    level_screen = new LevelScreen(this);
    return level_screen;
}

public Screen setHelpScreen() {
    help_screen = new HelpScreen(this);
    return game_screen;
}

}
```

thats the main class

i have create 4 Assets class AssetsLevel (with assets for level screen) AssetsMenu (with Assets for Menu Screen) AssetsGame (with Assets for the game) etc..

AssetsMenu :

```
public class AssetsMenu {

    public static Texture texture_menuback;
    public static Sprite menuback;

    public static Stage stagemenu;
    public static TextureAtlas atlasmenu;
    public static Button playbutton;
    public static ButtonStyle playbuttonstyle;
    public static Button helpbutton;
    public static ButtonStyle helpbuttonstyle;
    public static Button settingsbutton;
    public static ButtonStyle settingsbuttonstyle;
    public static Button quitbutton;
    public static ButtonStyle quitbuttonstyle;
    public static Skin skinmenu;

    public static void load(){

          stagemenu = new Stage();
            skinmenu = new Skin();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stagemenu);
            atlasmenu = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("gamemenu.atlas")); 
            skinmenu.addRegions(atlasmenu);
            playbuttonstyle = new ButtonStyle();
            playbuttonstyle.up = skinmenu.getDrawable("Play");
            playbuttonstyle.down = skinmenu.getDrawable("PlayClick");
            playbutton = new Button(playbuttonstyle);
            playbutton.setSize((360*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, (50*Gdx.graphics.getHeight())/480);
            playbutton.setPosition((150*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, 300);
            helpbuttonstyle = new ButtonStyle();
            helpbuttonstyle.up = skinmenu.getDrawable("Help");
            helpbuttonstyle.down = skinmenu.getDrawable("HelpClick");
            helpbutton = new Button(helpbuttonstyle);
            helpbutton.setSize((360*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, (50*Gdx.graphics.getHeight())/480);
            helpbutton.setPosition((150*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, 240);
            settingsbuttonstyle = new ButtonStyle();
            settingsbuttonstyle.up = skinmenu.getDrawable("Settings");
            settingsbuttonstyle.down = skinmenu.getDrawable("SettingsClick");
            settingsbutton = new Button(settingsbuttonstyle);
            settingsbutton.setSize((360*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, (50*Gdx.graphics.getHeight())/480);
            settingsbutton.setPosition((150*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, 180);
            quitbuttonstyle = new ButtonStyle();
            quitbuttonstyle.up = skinmenu.getDrawable("Exit");
            quitbuttonstyle.down = skinmenu.getDrawable("ExitClick");
            quitbutton = new Button(quitbuttonstyle);
            quitbutton.setSize((360*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, (50*Gdx.graphics.getHeight())/480);
            quitbutton.setPosition((150*Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/640, 120);
            stagemenu.addActor(playbutton);
            stagemenu.addActor(helpbutton);
            stagemenu.addActor(settingsbutton);
            stagemenu.addActor(quitbutton);
    }
}
```

when i click Play then must show level screen but not.. ram increase and some times show level screen

MainMenuScreen :

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

    MyGame game;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Vector3 touch;


    Orientation orientation;

    public static MainMenuScreen level_screen;

    int delay = 5;

    public MainMenuScreen(MyGame game){
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true,1800,1800);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        touch = new Vector3();

        orientation = Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F, 255F, 0F, 1F);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        generalUpdate(touch, camera);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
            AssetsMenu.stagemenu.draw();
        batch.end();

    }

    private void generalUpdate(Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera) {
        AssetsMenu.playbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                AssetsLevel.load();
                game.setScreen(game.setLevelScreen());
            }
        });

        AssetsMenu.settingsbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

            }
        });

        AssetsMenu.helpbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                game.setScreen(game.level_screen);
            }
        });

        AssetsMenu.quitbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        AssetsMenu.atlasmenu.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        AssetsMenu.stagemenu.dispose();
        AssetsMenu.skinmenu.dispose();
    }

}
```

loading screen :

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen {

    MyGame game;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Vector3 touch;

    Orientation orientation;

    Stage stage;
    TextureAtlas atlas;
    Button level1button;
    ButtonStyle level1buttonstyle;
    Button level2button;
    ButtonStyle level2buttonstyle;
    Button level3button;
    ButtonStyle level3buttonstyle;
    Skin skin;

    public static GameScreen game_screen;

    static float stateTime;

    public LoadingScreen(MyGame game){
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true,1800,1800);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        touch = new Vector3();

        orientation = Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F, 255F, 0F, 1F);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        AssetsLoad.loadingcurrentFrame = AssetsLoad.loadingAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

        camera.update();

        generalUpdate(touch, camera);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
            batch.draw(AssetsLoad.logo, 180, 200);
            batch.draw(AssetsLoad.loadingcurrentFrame, 770, 750);
        batch.end();

    }

    private void generalUpdate(Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera) {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        AssetsLoad.loadingSheet.dispose();
        AssetsLoad.texture_logo.dispose();
    }

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Did you tried using the debugger?... Try setting breakpoints to the critical parts and find out what happens.

Comment: i did but i cant ram increas after break point i cant find why that happened

Comment: Can you post your LoadingScreen class? By the way, (not that this is causing your issue) your MainMenuScreen's  generalUpdate method is needlessly creating new listeners for all your buttons every frame. I would not recommend making your assets classes static. Those need to dispose of resources.

Comment: loading screen added hmm so i have to put buttons in MainMenuScreen class? Not in general update?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you.. now is better i put in MainMenuScreen and LevelScreen in MainMenuScreen and LevelScreen class not in generalUpdate but i must change parametre Mygame Game to final ! its ok?
Now cost about 90mb ram i think for a simple game is too much :/

Comment: It sounds like your game has barely more than a menu right now, so if it's using more than 5-10MB, there must be a bug somewhere. But I don't see it in the code you've posted.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i have many stages and screens main menu level screen paused screen i think is normal.